# Dynamically create vCard

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

I was wondering what is the best way to create vCard. I don't need to store it on my server, just generate it when user wants to download it. The below code works, but it seems clumsy to me, is there any better way?

```
<?php
function raf_create_vcard(){
$format_name = utf8_encode($name);
$format_email = utf8_encode($email);
$format_tel = utf8_encode($tel);
$format_fax = utf8_encode($fax);
$format_www = utf8_encode($www);
$format_address = utf8_encode($address);

return 'BEGIN%3AVCARD%0D%0AVERSION%3A4.0%0D%0AN%3A%3B'.$format_name.'%3B%3B%3B%0D%0AFN%3A'.$format_name.'%0D%0AEMAIL%3A'.$format_email.'%0D%0AORG%3A'.$format_name.'%0D%0ATEL%3A'.$format_tel.'%0D%0ATEL%3Btype%3DFAX%3A'.$format_fax.'%0D%0AURL%3Btype%3Dpref%3A'.$format_www.'%0D%0AADR%3A%3B'.$format_address.'%3B%3B%3B%3B%3BSpain%0D%0AEND%3AVCARD';   
}
?>
```

Generating link:

```
<a href="data:text/plain;charset=UTF-8,<?php echo raf_create_vcard(); ?>" download="contact.vcf">Download</a>
```

Comment: The solutions below (particularly the use of the library) should be considered, but I'd like to add that you're better off with your `href` link being `'data:text/vcard;base64,' . base64_encode(raf_create_vcard())`, because the browser will interpret plain text line endings depending on the host OS and that will generate off-spec vCards, which will not be done with base64 encoded strings.

Comment: This is the best solution I found: https://mrweb.github.io/php/2020/05/27/php-vcard-ios-and-mobile-download.html

Comment: @Mr.Web any chance you help me to implement your code. When trying your code my page breaks. IDK what im doing wrong.

Comment: @RodrigoZuluaga are you using it with Laravel with my code, have you installed the package?

Comment: @mr.web im using normal .php for wordpress any help will be really awsome.
Just trying to create a simple download button, but im grabbing each person data dinamicaly from a simple wordpress variable.

Answer (score 9):

Add url link in **`<a>`** tag for generate Vcard like

```
<a href="vcard.php?id=1">Generate VCard</a>
```

You write a code directly in php file
save below code in **vcard.php** file

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');

  $sql="SELECT * FROM USER WHERE id=".$_GET['id'];
  $result=mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));
  // define here all the variable like $name,$image,$company_name & all other
  header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');  
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename= "'.$name.'.vcf"');  

  if($image!=""){ 
    $getPhoto               = file_get_contents($image);
    $b64vcard               = base64_encode($getPhoto);
    $b64mline               = chunk_split($b64vcard,74,"\n");
    $b64final               = preg_replace('/(.+)/', ' $1', $b64mline);
    $photo                  = $b64final;
  }
  $vCard = "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
  $vCard .= "VERSION:3.0\r\n";
  $vCard .= "FN:" . $name . "\r\n";
  $vCard .= "TITLE:" . $company_name . "\r\n";

  if($email){
    $vCard .= "EMAIL;TYPE=internet,pref:" . $email . "\r\n";
  }
  if($getPhoto){
    $vCard .= "PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:";
    $vCard .= $photo . "\r\n";
  }

  if($mobile_no){
    $vCard .= "TEL;TYPE=work,voice:" . $mobile_no . "\r\n"; 
  }

  $vCard .= "END:VCARD\r\n";
  echo $vCard;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a library you could write it like that:

```
function raf_create_vcard(){
    return utf8_encode('BEGIN:VCARD
        VERSION:4.0
        N:;'.$name.';;;
        FN:'.$name.'
        EMAIL:'.$email.'
        ORG:'.$name.'
        TEL:'.$tel.'
        TEL;type=FAX:'.$fax.'
        URL;type=PREF:'.$www.'
        ADR:;'.$address.';;;;;Spain
        END:VCARD');
}
```

But you should use a PHP library for that purpose. Check this out: https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard.

```
use JeroenDesloovere\VCard\VCard;

$vcard = new VCard();

$vcard->addName($name);
$vcard->addCompany($name);
$vcard->addEmail($email);
$vcard->addPhoneNumber($tel);
$vcard->addPhoneNumber($fax, 'FAX');
$vcard->addURL($www, 'PREF');
$vcard->addAddress($address, null, null, null, null, null, 'Spain');

$vcardAsString = $vcard->getOutput();
```

Comment: Im trying to implement this in a wordpress.
The Vcard info is dinamically inserted by post ID.
Any advice how to implement this because is breaking my site.

Comment: You really should not use a library for that purpose.

Comment: I highly recommend the usage of libraries when working with formats. A good library will handle escaping, help reduce flaws caused by semantic typos and ensure good compatibility. In this case it especially doesn't matter as the library is executed server side and probably not resource heavy. So, cheap maintenance, cheap compatibility, cheap security.

Answer (score 0):

**For Laravel**

*install using package ....*

```
composer require jeroendesloovere/vcard dev-master
```

**then in your controller**

```
      public function downloadVcard(/* Request $request */)
    {
     
      $vcard = new VCard();

      // define variables
         $lastname = 'Desloovere';
         $firstname = 'Jeroen';
         $additional = '';
         $prefix = '';
         $suffix = '';

      // add personal data
      $vcard->addName($lastname, $firstname, $additional, $prefix, $suffix);

      // add work data
      $vcard->addCompany('Siesqo');
      $vcard->addJobtitle('Web Developer');
      $vcard->addRole('Data Protection Officer');
      $vcard->addEmail('info@jeroendesloovere.be');
      $vcard->addPhoneNumber(1234121212, 'PREF;WORK');
      $vcard->addPhoneNumber(123456789, 'WORK');
      $vcard->addAddress(null, null, 'street', 'worktown', null, 'workpostcode', 
      'Belgium');
      $vcard->addLabel('street, worktown, workpostcode Belgium');
      $vcard->addURL('http://www.jeroendesloovere.be');

      //$vcard->addPhoto(__DIR__ . '/landscape.jpeg');

      // return vcard as a string
      //return $vcard->getOutput();

      // return vcard as a download
      return $vcard->download();
      }
```

**Route in web.php**

```
 Route::get('/downloadcard', 'App\Http\Controllers\VCardController@downloadVcard');
```